# TypeError : 1 required positional argument, Discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to work with custom event of discord.py and this is the error I stumbled upon
IG the ctx in `on profanity` is the problem but I need to identify which guild it is
I tried removing the if statement and it worked but when I add `if statement` it shows this error

````py
@commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        for i in self.badwords:
            if i.lower() in message.content.lower() or i.upper() in message.content.upper():
                await message.delete()
                await message.channel.send(f"{message.author.mention} you cannot use that word here")
                self.bot.dispatch('profanity', message, i)
                return
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_profanity(self, ctx, message, word):
        if ctx.guild.id == 841550614344237057:
            channel = self.bot.get_channel(847342532438655017)
            embed = discord.Embed(title='**PROFANITY ALERT**',
                                  description=f"{message.author.name} just said the word ||{word}||", color=discord.Color.blurple()
                                  )
            await channel.send(embed=embed)```

```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: on_profanity() missing 1 required positional argument: 'word'
````

Comment: You have to take ctx from somewhere and pass it to the bot.dispatch method.

Answer (score 2):

The error is pretty self-explanatory, you need ctx and you are not passing it, we can get the ctx and pass it or not use it as an argument.

Getting the ctx

```py
ctx = await self.bot.get_context(message)
self.bot.dispatch('profanity', ctx, message, i)
```

or
Remove ctx as an argument

```py
async def on_profanity(self, message, word):
   ctx. = await self.bot.get_context(message)
```

both essentially do the same thing and get the context for us.

### References:

- [get_context](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=get_context#discord.ext.commands.Bot.get_context)